# How to add an array inside another array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, yii2

I have this JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 101,
    "name": "White"
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "name": "Black"
  }
]
```

It was generated by my `**actionIndex()**` function and **Yii2 Framework**:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $colors = Colors::find()
        ->select([
            'id',
            'name'
        ])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

    return $colors;
}
```

I need to add some text to the array. The result has to be like this:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "error_message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 101,
      "name": "White"
    },
    {
      "id": 102,
      "name": "Black"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) function but it doesn't work:

```
$father = [];
array_push($father, $colors);
```

Comment: You can just create a new array and specific `error`, `error_message` and then `data` which contains your array

Comment: Roby, please mark my answer as accepted in case it solve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP add an array inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616832/php-add-an-array-inside-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could solve your issue:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $response = ['error'=>false, 'error_message'=>null];
    $response['data'] = Colors::find()
        ->select([
            'id',
            'name'
        ])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();


    return $response;
}
```

Since Output of this function is JSON response which is being converted from array we are retuning. So I have initialize the $response array with default values and then on 'data' index of the assign the array of colors. So it will give desire result as expected.

Comment: You should explain what you actually did to make this work. In it's current form it's largely a "code only answer" which is not really very beneficial overall (even if it helps OP immediately, it will not really help future visitors or anyone who actually wants to learn)